# What is the difference between DefaultSelenium and RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: selenium

Is RemoteWebDriver a replacement for DefaultSelenium in Selenium 2.0 or can the two be used in conjunction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RemoteWebDriver is simply the driver for connecting to a remote selenium server.  You can use WebDriver and old Selenium together with WebDriverBackedSelenium, which extends from DefaultSelenium.

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://remoteServer:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());

Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, START_URL);
```

Comment: Thanks, so should I be using WebDriverBackedSelenium or RemoteWebDriver to then control the browser?

Comment: @Paul - WebDriverBackedSelenium will be the one responsible for sending commands to the browser.  Use of WebDriverBackedSelenium is only necessary if you are supporting old Selenium tests.  If you are starting with brand new tests, I recommend going with the new way of using a browser specific driver.

Comment: In provided example WebDriverBackedSelenium will only work as WebDriver not as RemoteWebDriver, since the constructor accepts WebDriver interface as parameter. I have tested it and that's exactly how it behaves.

Comment: @dex1304 that comment is really useful - seems like a massive omission on the part of the selenium documentation.  They also seem to use Webdriver versus Selenium RC interchangeably in some places and then emphasise the differences in others!  I've been struggling to get something up and running for about a day now.

Answer (score 0):

`RemoteWebDriver` and `DefaultSelenium` can be used together like it is stated on this [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeleniumEmulation#Backing_Selenium_with). So for Java code it would be:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
String sessionId = (String) driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("webdriver.remote.sessionid");
DefaultSelenium selenium = DefaultSelenium('localhost', '4444', '*webdriver', 'http://www.google.com');
selenium.start("webdriver.remote.sessionid=" + sessionId);
```

The emphasis is on the word `*webdriver`.