# IE8 window opened from selenium remote console claimes it`s IE8 but acts like IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, internet-explorer-8, selenium-rc

I have a problem when using selenium 2.5 on IE8 through remote console. In the page that is opened by the remote console sometimes (but quite often) the javascript behaves as if it was running on IE7 - JSON is missing, setAttribute('style', something) does not render the styles. However it tells about itself it is IE8.

```
navigator.appVersion //returns "4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;Trident/4.0)"

document.documentMode //returns 8
```

I`ve managed to get the remote console window to run on IE8, but it does not mitigate the problem in the window that gets opened by the remote console (and in which the test is running). 
I have also added the meta-tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

I am working on XP mode, IE8 version 8.0.6001.18702.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I am working on XP mode" - So you aren't actually on XP? Or you are but in compatibility mode?

Comment: Selenium 2.5? Old version... Try upgrading to the latest version first: 2.28.

Comment: @Neurofluxation it is Windows XP Mode virtual PC on Windows 7 (IE8 is installed in the virtual machine)

Comment: @asgoth Unfortunately the problem persists for version 2.28. I was using 2.21 before, sorry for the mistification.

Comment: Can you add in your question how you define your ie cabalilities?

Comment: @asgoth If I understand correctly you are asking how do I decide that it does not behave correctly?

1) Visualy - I have put a sleep value where my test was failing, so the window would not closed, than opened developer tools and tried setting the style attribute for an element and saw nothing happened *(To be sure I had my functions correct I was doing the same in chrome and it worked).
2) By typing JSON to developer tools script and getting undefined.

Comment: 3) From Java by using
{Boolean.parseBoolean(
       selenium.getEval("windowMgr.getCurrent()['JSON'] !== undefined && windowMgr.getCurrent()['JSON'] !== null"))} - this is what I actualy recently check for in a while loop after the page load and if it failes I do reload. But I am not really satisfied with this fix, as it slows down the automated builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create your RemoteWebDriver like this (but then probably another ip):

```
DesiredCapabilities ie = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ie.set(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
ie.setCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "8");

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, ie);
```

Comment: Hi @asgoth, and many thanks for the tip. I am using the selenium by DefaultSelenium(seleniumHost, seleniumPort, browser, targetHost). Now I see that DefaultSelenium can wrap RemoteWebDriver [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539569/what-is-the-difference-between-defaultselenium-and-remotewebdriver), I just get confused How to use the urls properly. Could you help me out here as well?

Comment: DefaultSelenium is the old implementation. If possible, try to get rid of it and use [WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). [Here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp#migrating-to-webdriver-reference) you will find help migrating.

Comment: Many thanks, I will need to evaluate if I would have time for that, because it would require quite a lot of work in my case.